# HiveQL - How to use escaped keywords in a WHERE clause?

Tags: hiveql, amazon-emr, beeline

I am trying to query a table by selecting only those cases that meet a certain condition. It is a query called from Beeline, within a R script.
The problem is the field that must meet this condition has a reserved word as a column name: 'table'.

Whenever I run this in an AWS-EMR cluster:

> SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE `table` = 'something' AND year = 2018

I get the following error:

> **bash: table: command not found**
>
> Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
>
> Connected to: Apache Hive (version 2.3.2-amzn-0)
>
> Driver: Hive JDBC (version 2.3.2-amzn-0)
>
> Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
>
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . **Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:242 cannot recognize input near '=' ''something'' 'and' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)**
>
> Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
>
> ExitValue: 1

Both blocks marked in bold style should be fixed. Notice that the keyword 'table' is already escaped with backticks.

I have searched the web, but still cannot find a proper solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What tool do you "run" that SQL query into, that `bash` tries to parse the SQL?!?!?

Comment: Beeline called from an R script. It is crazy, I know... The magic of 'as is' projects...

Comment: Short-term workaround: try escaping back-ticks i.e. `\\`table\\`` or maybe `\\\`table\\\``

Comment: Long-term fix: use `RJDBC` to run Hive queries straight from R.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, the short-term workaround of double back-slashes worked like a charm for me. Thanks!
I will post your answer as the right one, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SamsonScharfrichter pointed out in the comments:

> Short-term workaround: try escaping back-ticks i.e. \`table\` or maybe \\`table\\`

This worked for my problem.

Comment: You have to escape the escapes once more.. because of the Markdown syntax used by S.O.

Comment: Actually, it was twice more! Four backslashes in the second case, funny! Thanks for noticing!